# MPI_Win_fence hangs

Tags: mpi, mpi-rma

I have implemented a kind of distributed array for a specific application using MPI. I have tried to use RMA (MPI_Get) to get updated values for the portion of the array which is under responsibility of other processes.
  We have done what is specified at tutorials:
MPI_Win_create
MPI_Win_fence
a bunch of MPI_Get (circa 8.000 per processes)
MPI_Win_fence

The problem is that all processes hang at the second MPI_Win_fence and never returns.
Can anyone give some help? Is the number of MPI_Get a problem?

Regards,
Adenilso

Comment: Impossible to answer without more code.  Could be a bug in RMA, could be an issue with your program.  Can't say unless you provide example code.

Comment: Ok. I will prepare a cleaned-up code. However, if I artificially restrain the number of MPI_Get's each process executed to, say, 100, the program progresses normally.

Comment: That's perfect.  A small-ish code that works with a small number of outstanding gets but breaks with lots of gets would either a: show the problem or b: make a great bug report against your MPI implementation.  What mpi implementation are you using, anyway?